# How do I remove the row index column from ag-grid for R (RagGrid)?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, ag-grid

I cannot figure out how to remove the first column from the table since the column header is blank. Is there an option for removing this column or how can I access by column index? Again, I am using R, but JS could work as well.

```
library(shiny)
library(RagGrid)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  title = 'Use the RagGrid package in shiny',
  fluidRow(
    column(2),
    column(8, RagGrid::RagGridOutput('tbl1')),
    column(2)
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl1 <- renderRagGrid(aggrid(iris))
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note: ag-grid puts this column in automatically, it is not actually in the underlying data frame. [See example table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWl76.png)

Comment: Please provide data in a [reproducible manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), not as an image.

Answer (score -1):

This removes the first column, regardless of its name:

```
dataframe[,-1]
```

Comment: ag-grid puts the column in automatically, its not in the underlying data